# Cross origin on fabric.Image.fromURL breaks CORS even with crossOrigin set

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, fabricjs, amazon-cloudfront

Using fabric.js I'm attempting to load a background image from an amazon cloudfront/s3 url.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(imgURL, function(img) {
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    {
        scaleX: canvas.width / img.width,
        scaleY: canvas.height / img.height
    });
}, {crossOrigin: 'anonymous'});
```

When crossOrigin is present, I get the standard error

```
Access to image at '...' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

When I remove the crossOrigin anon. It will load the image, however it taints the canvas so that I cannot use `toDataURL`.

[image: CORS Headers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I remove the crossOrigin anon. It will load the image, however it taints the canvas so that I cannot use toDataURL.

This is the default position. If you don't specify it, then it won't allow you to do anything that requires CORS permission.

> When crossOrigin is present, I get the standard error
>
> Access to image at '...' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

`anonymous` means "Check for CORS permission, but don't send user credentials to a different origin".

So instead of **just** forbidding access to features that need CORS permission, it first checks for CORS permission, discovers that you don't have it, **then** forbids access.

You need the server you are requesting the image from to provide your JavaScript with permission to read the data using CORS.

Comment: The CORS policy is permissive already on S3 what else could I be missing?

Comment: @NeilAshleyHickman — The error message says "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." … so the CORS policy is not set properly there.

Comment: For anyone looking at this question later down the line. if you update your CORS policy on AWS....... clear your cache.

Comment: Hi @Llanilek, a client is having this problem — we have a CORS configuration in place, we've cleared cache, but we're still seeing it, and have to open the developer tools to stop it.